# Webbrowser control - how do I see list of files (css, js, etc) that has been downloaded when navigating to a website?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I would like to see a list of downloaded files when navigating to a new webpage in a webbrowser control. I can see them all using Google's Developer Tools (css, javascript, images, etc). But I can't seem to find it in the WebBrowser control.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + e.Url + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

The DocumentCompleted event is raised a few times, but only for the main page and banner urls. If I navigate to reddit.com, I see a long list of GET's of maybe 40-50 different files downloaded. How do I see them and access them in the WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Create a pass-through [Pluggable Protocol Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `http` and `https:` protocols. Any URL request would go through it.
- Run an in-process proxy server for your `WebBrowser` process, register it with `UrlMkSetSessionOption` and track all `GET` requests.